# python multithreading 10 thread at a time until 200 thread completed

Tags: python, multithreading

i have 200 SQL Servers and 40 same tables in all servers. i want to execute my python data pipeline per table in all 200 threads. just want know if i can run 10 thread concurrently at a time and if they finish, it run next 10 thread until 200 thread completed in one job automatically

```
for index, row in shops.iterrows():
    tf =isOpen(row['shop_ip'] , row['port'])
    endTime = time.time()
    pingTime = endTime-startTime
    if tf:
        print(f"UP {row['shop_ip']} Ping Successful Time Taken : "+str(pingTime)+" seconds")
        x = threading.Thread(target=ETLScript.ETLLoadingShopPos,args=(SelectColumns,tableName,tableName,row['shop_code'],'where 1=1',str(row['shop_code']),row))
        jobs.append(x)
        x.start()
        x.join()
```

Comment: It's certainly possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i updated my post please check my code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, is it matter to run 10 thread as a running group or the matter thing is only 10 thread is allowed to run?

I think queue concept will works

```
import time
import threading

jobs = []

for index, row in shops.iterrows():
    tf =isOpen(row['shop_ip'] , row['port'])
    endTime = time.time()
    pingTime = endTime-startTime
    if tf:
        while sum([j.is_alive() for j in jobs]) >= 10:
            time.sleep(0.3) # give it a range to check to avoid resource consumed the whole time by main thread                            
        print(f"UP {row['shop_ip']} Ping Successful Time Taken : "+str(pingTime)+" seconds")
        x = threading.Thread(target=ETLScript.ETLLoadingShopPos,args=(SelectColumns,tableName,tableName,row['shop_code'],'where 1=1',str(row['shop_code']),row))
        jobs.append(x)
        x.start()
```

This allows you to run 10 threads at once. `while` loop will be used as a blocker to check if any of those threads is finished, another new thread will be started.

Comment: Thanks danangjoyoo but your strategy keep adding rest other threads i wanna 10 thread at a time if thread finish it will add one thread from queue  1 .... 100  ( runing 10 - 1 finish + 1 add from queue is it possible)

Comment: well it works like that, don't you see my description and using `while` loop to block the generation of thread if its already 10 threads? you dont event try my code dont you?

Comment: hope you know how this line works `while sum([j.is_alive() for j in jobs]) >= 10: time.sleep(0.3)`

Comment: thanks .. its working actually job [] list variable was inside my loop there for it was refreshing every time   now i declare it out side loop and its  working

Comment: Ah yea, I forgot about it. Nice catch tho

Comment: if my code works, could you please close this question bcs already answered and vote up my answer? thanks